# Limit of a rational function where denominator approaches zero

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to solve $$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x+5}{x-4} $$

Since the numerator and denominator both increase without bound, I try to get something more useful by dividing everything by $ x $.

$$ 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3x+5}{x-4}  
 = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{3x+5}{x}}{\frac{x-4}{x}}
 = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3 + \frac{5}{x}}{ \frac{-4}{x} }
 = \frac{ \lim_{x\to\infty} 3 + \frac{5}{x} }{ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{-4}{x}}
\end{align}
$$

This gets me a numerator approaching 3 and a denominator approaching zero. But since the quotient law for limits specifically excludes a zero denominator, I don't know what do from here.

Wolfram Alpha says the limit is 3 (and a graph agrees) so I think I'm on the right track, but I have a feeling I messed up the algebra somewhere.

Thanks.

Comment: You dropped a term from your denominator in the third step; it should be $1 - \frac{4}{x}$.

Comment: Right you are! I suspected it was a dumb algebra mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{x-4}{x}&=&\frac{x}{x}-\frac{4}{x} \\ &=& 1 - \frac{4}{x} \end{eqnarray*}$

Comment: Thanks -- my suspicion of an algebra mistake was correct. Now I get 3/1 which makes everything work.

Comment: @DLim: Thank you for the editing in the extra step to clarify. (Really, no reason to apologize.)